# Using Matlab Structure Data Type in Java

Tags: java, matlab, oop, data-structures, struct

I am beginner in Java. I have some codes in MATLAB and I use structures.`inf.time.leap = [];inf.time.last = 86400;` But java doesn't have structure data types. I should be able to get all the values ​​(leap, last etc.) with data types in the function from a different function. So, I created classes in java for all structure arrays and variables.

For example;

```java
public class Inf {

    Time1 t;
    Seq1 s;
    Nob1 n;
    Rinex1 r;
    Sat1 sa;
    Rec1 re;
    Ant1 an;
    Lst1 ls;

    public Inf() {}
}

public class Time1 {
    double leap;
    double int1;
    double[] last;
    double[] first;
    String system;
    double doy;
}
```

But I have so much classes this way. Would you suggest an easier way?

Actually, I want to convert matlab codes to java. I created values ​​in MATLAB in structure. For example "inf" has "time" structure inside.
There are "leap", "int", "last," "first" values ​​in "time".

```
inf.time.leap = [];inf.time.last = 86400;
```

Another example is "sequence" inside inf. There are values ​​such as "gps", "glonass" in the sequence.

```
inf.seq.gps    = cell(1);
```

Since there is no structure type in java, I created classes for all these values. There are 8 classes ​​in total in inf. (Time1,Seq1, Nob1,Rinex1, Sat1,Rec1, Ant1,Lst1) I created a class for all of these values.I gave class examples in my question.
I have assigned values ​​to variables such as leap, int, last inside the function. Code sample;

```
public class dnm2 {
    public Inf infOku() throws IOException {
    
        
        Inf isimInf = new Inf();
        Time1 isimTime = new Time1();
        Seq1 isimSeq = new Seq1();
        Nob1 isimNob = new Nob1();
        Rinex1 isimRinex = new Rinex1();
        Sat1 isimSat = new Sat1();
        Rec1 isimRec = new Rec1();
        Ant1 isimAnt = new Ant1();
        Lst1 isimLst = new Lst1();
        isimInf.t = isimTime;
        isimInf.s = isimSeq;
        isimInf.n = isimNob;
        isimInf.r = isimRinex;
        isimInf.sa = isimSat;
        isimInf.re = isimRec;
        isimInf.an = isimAnt;
        isimInf.ls = isimLst;
    
    

    isimTime.leap = 0;
    isimTime.int1 = 0;
```

I need to call the method that I assign values ​​for leap, int1 etc. in other functions and access these variables with their own data type(double,int,double[] etc).
I did it this way;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    dnm2 dnmYazo = new dnm2();
        
    Inf isimInf = new Inf();

    isimInf = dnmYazo.infOku();
}
```

Currently, the codes I created works without any problems. but I wonder if I can handle it in a shorter way without creating 8 or more classes like this  (creating classes for time1, seq1, nob1 etc).

Comment: Hello, i edited my question by more explanation.